# How do I keep KDE from asking new users for a password when I use /etc/skel to set up their environment?

Tags: linux, permissions, arch-linux, kde, password

I made this nice custom KDE setup on Arch Linux with customised settings like desktop background, panel settings, kwin settings, etc.  I heard that if you copy all the hidden files from your `/home/"dummy user"/` to `/etc/skel` it would copy my settings exactly the way they are from "dummy user" to all newly created users created after this procedure.

I got what I wanted, which is copying my desktop interface to all newly created users on the system.  But it keeps giving me all these password windows saying I need permission from "dummy user" to use certain files and apps like Nepomuk.  How do I get these prompts to go away so the next user I make doesn't see them? What files do I stay away from to avoid hitting user specific data?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me some configurations have absolute paths to your dummy user's home, you might need to change that to get rid of those password windows.

```
find /home/nextuser/.kde* -type f \
     -exec sed -i -e "s:/home/dummyuser:/home/nextuser:" {} +
```

Comment: what does this comand do?

Comment: It replaces the string "/home/dummyuser" by "/home/nextuser" where nextuser is your new user where the kde config has been copied.

Comment: so do i run this before i log in to the new user for the first time or after i log in because if it is after i log in it is pointless.

Comment: I'd run it before.